# Auto evaluate org mode source block on file save

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, hooks

For example, whenever I edit my config, I run this block to reload the config:

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :tangle no :var data=replace-symlink :results none
(org-babel-load-file (locate-user-emacs-file "/home/user/.emacs.d/config.org"))
(load-file "/home/user/.emacs.d/config.el")
#+end_src
```

Is there a way to have this run automatically every time I save the file `C-x C-s`?

I have another file with a src block that generates an xwiki file and updates a web wiki via an API. I'm trying to have org evaluate that block automatically on save as well.

Let me know if there's a straighforward way to do it. This would seem very useful functionality but I didn't come across anything in org docs. It might be [solved](https://orgmode.org/manual/Evaluating-Code-Blocks.html) already by creatively running `#+CALL` via some save hook?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `org-babel-ref-resolve` to call **named** code blocks from one of the hooks `before-save-hook` or `after-save-hook`.

Example Orgmode-file:

```
#+NAME: myblock
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(message "Running myblock.")
#+END_SRC

Local Variables:
eval: (add-hook 'before-save-hook (lambda () (org-babel-ref-resolve "myblock")) nil t)
End:
```

Comment: This is amazing. Thank you!